# how to input alphabets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

so i want to do the same with alphabets that i did with numbers take a look

```
num1=int(input("enter Ist digit:"))
num2=int(input("enter IInd digit:"))
num3=int(input("enter IIIrd digit:"))
num4=int(input("enter IVth digit:"))
num5=int(input("enter Vth digit:"))
```

i want to enter letters instead of numbers 
so i changed it to

```
alpha1=chr(input("enter Ist letter"))
```

but i kept on getting the error

```
   alpha1=chr(input("enter Ist alphabet:"))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: Python has no "character" data type. It's just `str()` which is redundant with input function

Answer (score 5):

Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr):

> chr(i)
>
> Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i.

and

> input([prompt])
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that

you don't need to convert the character. What you get from input is already a string

Answer (score 0):

simply 
     alpha1=input("enter Ist letter")

Answer (score 0):

Python consider standard input as string and in the first case it convert the string to integer. But in the second case it will not work as it get input as string and chr(param) always expect an integer value where param should be a integer value (0-9) . So just use like below:-

```
alpha1=(input("enter Ist alphabet:"))[0]
```